# Remotely debugging Python/Kivy with graphical support in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, remote-debugging

My first simple Kivy test runs fine on the remote Raspberry Pi 4, but when I run it in the VS Code debugger, it can't initialize the correct graphical driver:

```
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.....
sdl2 - RuntimeError: b'Could not initialize EGL'
  File "/home/pi/test/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 70, in core_select_lib`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is because VSCODE Remote SSH extension does not support X11 forwarding ...